# Foreign key Error Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

This generic error is annoying, how do i find out WHICH foreign key failed.

Answer (score 0):

As of I understood your problem,The actual error is the foreign key column in the table is not accepting null and the entry is not providing data for that column. If you have used fluent api , one option is you can change IsRequired() to IsOptional() for foreign key mapping